# Exchange hosted Office 365 - when a signature is setup in the OWA - should Outlook desktop pick up this sig?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, office365

I as told that when a signature is setup for a user in  OWA on the 365 hosted Exchange , Outlook should pick this up?
We created a signatures for all our users in OWA on 365 , selected "automatically include my signature on messages I send" .

When this account is created in Outlook 2010 desktop - using the autodiscovery - (not imap, or pop) the signatures are not showing.
I was told the OWA on 365 Office signatures propagate to any and all sent emails (even with third party apps) .
Is this not the case?
I am on the line with MS and they have no clue for some reason.

Comment: Are you trying to add a disclaimer text? http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/5988.aspx -- Perhaps you're confusing user signatures versus a global disclaimer text that you want to include when sending an e-mail outside the organization.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a compatible version of office installed to use this feature, beginning with Office 2013 - and then you must have installed the click-to-run version that will link the install to your office account.

So in summary - you need either Office 365 Pro (with download rights) or Office 365 E3 (or better), although there are workarounds, this is just the out-of-the-box method that is tried and true.